# Let $G$ be a group, $|G|=12$, $H\leq G, |H|=6 , \exists x\in G ,x\notin H $ such that $o(x)=2$. Prove $|Z(G)|=12$ or $|Z(G)|=2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group, $|G|=12$, $H\leq G, |H|=6, \exists x\in G,x\notin H$ such that $o(x)=2$. Prove $|Z(G)|=12$ or $|Z(G)|=2$.

My attempt:

$$Z(G)\leq G \implies |Z(G)|\mid |G| \implies |Z(G)|\mid 12.$$

Case 1: $$|Z(G)|=12 \implies G=Z(G),$$ so $G$ is an abelian group as required.

Case 2: $|Z(G)|=6 \implies H\triangleleft G, |G/Z(G)|=\frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}=2$ hence $G/Z(G)$ is a cyclic, which implies $G$ is abelian. Contradiction.

Case 3: $|Z(G)|=4$ the same  case as above. $|G/Z(G)|=\frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}=3$

Case 4: $|Z(G)|=3$  $|G/Z(G)|=\frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}=4$, which implies $G/Z(G)$ is abelian. I am stuck here.

Case 5: $|Z(G)|=2$ as required.

Case 6: $|Z(G)|=1$

I get stuck in case $4,6$

In addition I can conclude that $o(x^{-1}yx)=o(y)$

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: I would try & prove $$|Z(G)|\neq 12\implies |Z(G)|=2,$$ since for any propositions $P, Q$, we have $$(P\lor Q)\iff ((\lnot P)\implies Q).$$

Comment: Note that $H\lhd G$ (because it has index two).

Comment: Actually, a stronger result is true. Any group of order $12$ having a subgroup of order $6$ has a center of order $12$ or $2$. So we need not use the condition on the element $x$ of order $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $H$ is either isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$ or to $S_3$.
Just observe that if $H$ is cyclic then $G\cong H\rtimes \langle x\rangle$ and so $G$ is either $\Bbb Z_6\times \Bbb Z_2$ or $D_6$ (this is because ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_6)\cong \Bbb Z_2$, so there are at most $2$ isomorphism classes for $G$) and thus the centre has order $12$ or $2$.
Suppose that $H\cong S_3$. Take a $3$-cycle $a\in H$. Since $H$ is a normal subgroup the unique conjugate of $a$ in $G$ is $a^2$, so its conjugation class has order $2$ and then the centraliser of $a$ in $G$ is a subgroup of order $6$ with nontrivial centre and so this centraliser is a cyclic order 6 subgroup of $G$. Taking $x$ to be a transposition in $H$ we are again in the first case, thus we conclude.

Comment: Exactly that's the idea I want to give but I haven't able to clear my mind.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $|G|=12$ and $H\le G$ with $|H|=6$ imply $H\triangleleft G$.

Since $H$ contains an element of order $2$ (by Cauchy's Theorem), if $G$ has a unique element of order $2$, then $a\in G\setminus H$ with $|a|=2$ is impossible. Hence $G$ can't be $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ or *Dicylic* group.

---

Let $a\in G\setminus H$ such that $|a|=2$.
Then $K=\langle a\rangle \le G$ and $|K|=2$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$. Hence $G\cong H\rtimes_{\varphi} K$, where $\varphi: K\to \textrm{Aut}(H) $

---

Case $1$: $H\cong \Bbb{Z}_6$

Then $\varphi :K\cong \Bbb{Z}_2 \to \textrm{Aut}(H)\cong \Bbb{Z_2}$. Hence $G\cong \Bbb{Z_6}\times \Bbb{Z_2}$

---

Case $2$: $H\cong D_3$ (the dihedral group of order six).

Then $G\cong D_3 \rtimes \Bbb{Z_2}$.

Comment: Let me give few minutes. I am away from home.

Comment: No worries, @SouravGhosh; take your time.

Comment: I don't think $G$ can be $\Bbb Z_{12}$, since its subgroup of order two is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_6\le \Bbb Z_{12}$.

Comment: You need to show, in addition, that $G=HK$ in order to conclude it is a semidirect product.

Comment: $H\triangleleft G$ implies $HK\le G$ and $|HK|=12$ implies $G=HK$

Comment: But with $\Bbb Z_{12}$, the element of order two is in $H$ by uniqueness. This contradicts the definition of $H$.

Comment: Thank you, @SouravGhosh :)

Answer (score 1):

We can prove a stronger result. Any group of order $12$ having a subgroup of order $6$ has a center of order $12$ or $2$.

Indeed, either $G$ is abelian, or $G$ is not abelian. In the first case we have $|Z(G)|=12$, and in the second case we know that $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $12$, hence isomorphic to one of the groups $A_4, Dic_3$ or $D_6$ - see this reference, among others:

[Classifying groups of order $12$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799614/classifying-groups-of-order-12?noredirect=1&lq=1)

We know that $|Z(A_4)|=1$, and also that $A_4$ has no subgroup $H$ of order $6$. On the other hand, $|Z(D_6)|=2$, and $D_6$ has subgroups of order $6$, for example $C_6$ generated by the rotations. The dicyclic group $Dic_3$ also satisfies $|Z(Dic_3)|=2$, so we are done.

Comment: Since $H$ contains an element of order $2$ (by Cauchy's Theorem), if $G$ has a unique element of order $2$, then $a\in G\setminus H$ with $|a|=2$ is impossible.Hence $G$ can't be $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ or *Dicylic* group.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, but the question in principle is answered if we know that a group $G$ of order $12$ having a subgroup $H$ of order $6$ has center of order $12$ or $2$. We can just ignore the order $2$ condition - it may, or it may not be satisfied. In any case, $Z(G)$ has order $2$ or $12$. So we have proved a stronger result.

Answer (score 1):

If $|Z(G)|=6$ or $|Z(G)|=4$, then $G/Z(G)$  is nontrivial and cyclic: contradiction, as no such a group exists.

If $|Z(G)|=3$, then every noncentral element has centralizer of order $3$ or $6$, and hence the class equation yields:
$$12=3+4k+2l$$
contradiction, because $2\nmid 3$.

So we are left with ruling out the case $G$ centerless. Suppose it is; then, every nontrivial element has centralizer of order $2$, or $3$, or $4$, or $6$. The class equation then yields:
$$12=1+6k+4l+3m+2n \tag1$$
or, equivalently:
$$11-3m=2(3k+2l+n) \tag2$$
Therefore, $m=1$ or $m=3$. If $m=1$, then $(2)$ yields:
$$4=3k+2l+n$$
which is fulfilled by $(k,l,n)=$ $(1,0,1)$, $(0,0,4)$, $(0,1,2)$, $(0,2,0)$. If $m=3$, then $(2)$ yields:
$$1=3k+2l+n$$
which is fulfilled by $(k,l,n)=(0,0,1)$, only.

For $(m,k,l,n)=(1,1,0,1)$, $(1,0,0,4)$, $(1,0,1,2)$, $(1,0,2,0)$, the latter three 4-tuples lead to conjugacy classes setups which do not allow any union of size $6$, and hence not any normal subgroup of such an order is possible. The same conclusion holds for $(m,k,l,n)=(3,0,0,1)$. So, we are left to prove that the class equation $(1)$ gotten from $(m,k,l,n)=(1,1,0,1)$, namely $$12=1+6+3+2$$ contradicts some assumption. And in fact, $H$ must be the union of the conjugacy classes of size $1$, $2$ and $3$, and hence *all* the six elements of the other one conjugacy class (which is $G\setminus H$) have order $2$, because by assumption *some* has; but then $H$ must have odd order (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/857686/1007416)): contradiction, because $H$ has order $6$.

So, finally, $|Z(G)|=12$ or $|Z(G)|=2$.